# How do you add a .txt file to a shell script as a variable

Tags: bash, shell

Hello guy I am trying to write a basic shell script that adds, creates or lists multiple user accounts from a provide list in the form of a file specified at the command line. I am very new to this and have been banging my head on the keyboard for the last few hours. below is an example of the syntax and the code so for. (I called this script buser)

./buser.sh -a userlist   (-a is the option and userlist is the filename, it is only an example)

```
file=$(< `pwd`/$2)

while :
do
case $1 in
   -a)
          useradd -m "$file"
          break
          ;;
   --add)
          useradd -m "$file"

          break
          ;;
   --delete)
          userdel -r "$file"
          break
          ;;
   -d)
          userdel -r "$file"
          break
          ;;
   -l)
          cat /etc/passwd | grep "$file"
          break
          ;;
   --list)
          cat /etc/passwd | grep "$file"
          break
          ;;
esac
done
```

when the useradd command reads $file it reads all the names as a single line and I get an error.

any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly.

But assuming you have a file with the following content:

```
**file.txt**
name1
name2
name3
```

You would like to call **buser.sh -a file.txt** and run useradd to name1, name2 and name3? I'm also assuming you're using Linux and useradd is the native program, if so I suggest to read the man, because it does not support to add a list of user at once (https://www.tecmint.com/add-users-in-linux/)

You have to call useradd multiple times instead.

```
while read user; 
do   
  useradd -m $user
done <$2
```

Comment: yes thats what I am trying to do, I added what you said and now it runs without an error but it only adds name1.

Comment: Add an extra line in the end of your file

Comment: I removed all the break lines and it all worked perfectly! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to create the commands, and eval to run them:

```
var=$( sed -e 's/^/useradd -m /' -e 's/$/;/' $file )
eval "$var"
```

(Edited to put in the -m flag.)

Comment: thank you for this. I haven't used sed before so now I'm reading through the man page its very interesting. thank you again.

Comment: That's what we're here for!

Answer (score 0):

A few simplifications, plus an error handler if the option doesn't exist:

```
while read file ; do
    case "$1" in
       -a|--add)
          useradd -m "$file"
          ;;
       -d|--delete)
          userdel -r "$file"
          ;;
       -l|--list)
          grep -f `pwd`/"$2"  /etc/passwd
          break
          ;;
       *) 
          echo "no such option as '$1'..."
          exit 2
          ;;
    esac
done < `pwd`/"$2"
```

Note: the above logic is a bit redundant... `case "$1"` keeps doing the same test, (with the same result), every pass.  OTOH, it works, and it's less code than a `while` loop in each command list.